# Python requests, keep getting 401 error when accessing an API

Tags: python, django, api, python-requests

I am trying to make a connection to this [API](https://gimbal.com/doc/rest.html) with requests.
Specifically I was trying to access the "all applications" endpoint, yet I am having trouble making an initial connection.

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "https://manager.gimbal.com/api/applications"
>>> headers = {
... 'Authorization': 'Token <MyApiKeyIsHere>',
... 'content-type': 'application/json'
... }
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [401]>
```

I am a bit confused as to why I am not getting an unauthorized connection to the API. If anyone can offer some pointers, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation seems to point out that the value is actually token=TOKEN, not just the token itself...

`AUTHORIZATION: Token token=my_organization_server_api_key`

Try replacing

```
'Authorization': 'Token <MyApiKeyIsHere>',
```

with this, and see if it responds properly

```
'Authorization': 'Token token=<MyApiKeyIsHere>',
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. I received Response [200]!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get result:

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "AUTHORIZATION: Token token=exxxx....xxxxxxxxxxxx6" https://manager.gimbal.com/api/applications

headers = {
... "Authorization: Token ",
... "content-type: application/json"
... }